# How can I check if php-pecl-solr is properly installed?

Tags: php, solr, pecl

I have installed php, php solrclient and php-pecl-solr and using solr 4.6.1. The Solr works properly through the UI(solr admin page) but when I try to give any command through a php file, the command doesn't return anything and is possibly not even working.
How can I check if the required modules are installed and running properly.
Even the following code doesn't display anything on the page.

```
 <?php

  $solr_version = solr_get_version();

  print $solr_version;

 ?>
```

Comment: Can I ask what was the issue? `solr_get_version()` doesn't seem to exist in my Solr 6.0.1 installation (returns false), even though on my dev server I can run Solr without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `php_info()`?

```
<?php 
php_info();
?>
```

This shows a list of all installed modules, extension etc. See the documentation for more details - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Just checked it, there is a segment for solr which shows quite a lot of extensions and modules that are installed, even the ones that i wasn't expecting, but still the codes don't give an output. Well i guess that it is entirely a different issue then and i must take it to another post! Thanks a lot Kami

Comment: Which version of the extension are you using?

Comment: I guess its 1.0.2. It was mentioned in one of the blogs that solr 4.6.1 is backwards compatible and this version of the extension is functional on solr 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using line command

```
wget -O- "http://solr_ip_adress.lan:8080/solr/admin/registry.jsp" | grep 'solr-spec-version'
```

Comment: Well that gives error 404. Anyways i discovered that the extensions are installed. There must be some other issue. Thanks anyways